# Is it possible to receive a Java update before its release?

Tags: java, java-7, updates

Java 7 Update 25 just released today and causes some functionality of the framework that my company develops on to fail. This has been happening for the past year with most of the Java updates. It would be nice if Oracle had some sort of developer agreement that allows companies to test the new update before its release that way the company has time to prepare to tackle any problems and inform their customers to be prepared.

If I had known these issues beforehand, I would not have updated to Java 7 Update 25 and would have informed my customers to wait until a patch is created to update. (Telling them to not update is way easier than having our support department explain how to access the Oracle JAVA archive and create a free Oracle login to access the installer.)

So my question is: Does anyone know of a way to receive a copy of new Java updates before its official release?

Comment: Not an answer, but a work-around.  Tell them never to update until it has been approved by you, and then you'll have a head start to install it, see what it breaks, patch and then approve the update.

Comment: An interesting option would be the possibility of making your Java installs check for updates in a place of your chosing.

Comment: Consider shipping a jre with your application, if the framework depends on the jre version that much

Comment: My understanding was you had to pay a licence fee to ship a JRE with your application.

Comment: Just out of curiosity since I seem to never run into such problems: What is the exact reason your framework is not running with the new Java version?

Comment: Perhaps the framework makes unwarranted assumptions about the JRE or the JVM, in which case you would be better off fixing the framework.

Comment: @eidsonator That was my first solution, unfortunately when trying to access a certain portion of our product via a web browser, you can either update or exit (rejecting the update still locks you out of this portion of our product [it is also part of the framework]) *jarnbjo and *Raedwald unfortunately we do not have control over updates on the framework (another company developed the framework that we develop on). That being said, the company that developed the framework should really be looking into this issue, but for the sake of the company that I work for, I am trying to do what I can.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oracle makes some new versions of Java available before official release under [Java Early Access](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/ea-jsp-142245.html) program.

Comment: Early access to updates that fix security vulnerabilities are only available to licensees, for very obvious reasons. (Around 6u3 was the last security release to have a public early access, and I found what was clearly a botched attempt to fix a vulnerability that I was not previously aware of.)

Answer (score 3):

You can usually get the next major release of Java through the early access program but I don't remember seeing early access to patch releases since they are normally fixing security issues and bugs rather than changing the API.

This is a two part problem. The first step is to better manage your customers and explain to them that updating the JVM without first checking with you may cause problems (I'd love it if our customers would update their VM so think yourself lucky).

The second step is to fix your framework so that it isn't doing whatever's causing so many breakages. I'm hard pushed to think of a time when any of our code has stopped working because of a patch release. I wonder if you are using any undocumented API which is just asking for trouble.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately we do not have control over the framework. We program on the framework developed by another company. They are [usually] pretty quick about fixing these sort of issues, but that never happens before the calls start coming in :-)